# How to setup Lambda/Step Functions such that I'm not billed while idling for API responses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Say I have a top level AWS Lambda function, called `order_for_all_clients`, and another Lambda function called `order_for_single_client`.

`order_for_all_clients` gathers up 1,000 clients, and makes a Step Function call to `order_for_single_client` for each one of them.

`order_for_single_client` has a workflow along these lines:

1. Place external API call, wait for response.
2. Based on #1, make another external API call, wait for response.
3. Based on #2, make another external API call, wait for response.

Within this function, 90% of the time is spent waiting for API calls to return a response. The other 10% is spent performing the actual processing/computation.

Is there a way to architect Lambda/Step Functions in such a way that it can fire off an API call, shut down the current Lambda function, and then re-initiate a Lambda function once the API call returns? In doing so, I will only be billed for actual computation time, and not be billed for time spent idling around waiting for API calls to return.

Comment: Do you have control over External APIs ? How long an API response takes? If you have control over external API then may be there is a way . We fire and forget the external API and when response is ready external API can resume step function with token and response string.  Is your order_for_all_clients is only to queue up all the API requests ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. There would be nothing to "receive" the API response.

A cleaner "async" solution would be to request the external service to send a response to an **Amazon SQS queue**, which could then trigger an AWS Lambda function. However, this would need a change to the way that the external service processes API requests.

Or, the external service might provide **separate API calls to 'submit' a request and then 'retrieve' the result of a request**. The Lambda function could 'submit' the request. Another process would then poll the service to retrieve the results for any jobs that have completed.

If you have many requests per second to the external service, it might be worth moving to Amazon EC2 and **make requests in parallel**. This would make greater use of the resources while waiting for a response.